# How to know/configure Xamarin Android generated package name?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-widget, xamarin.android, android-appwidget

I am required to specify full class name (including package name) for the Widget configuration activity like so:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:configure="my.package.MyConfigActivity"
    ...
>
</appwidget-provider>
```

But when I compile my app and look in the generated manifest file, I see that the name of the activity is changed to `md52e27f5924a30b693e8c2cbed2aefe779.MyConfigActivity`.

How do i get this generated name or set it somewhere so its predictable and I can use it in my appwidget-provider Xml config file?

Comment: Where do you compare this file name? If you are doing this in the Activity then you can get the package name and class name using `this.ComponenetName.PackageName` and `this.ComponentName.ClassName` respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xamarin auto-generates class ids if you do not specify one via an `Attribute`

Some examples:

#### Activity Naming:

```
[Activity(Label = "ActivityNaming", Name = "com.sushihangover.playscript.MyBigBadGame", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
  ~~~
}
```

#### Auto-generates into the Manifest:

```
<activity android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="ActivityNaming" android:name="com.sushihangover.playscript.MyBigBadGame">
  <intent-filter>
      ~~~~~
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

#### BroadcastReceiver Naming:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Name = "com.sushihangover.greatapp.MyReceiver")]
public class MyBroadCastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
       ~~~~
    }
}
```

#### Auto-generates into the Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.sushihangover.greatapp.MyReceiver" />
```

Comment: this works great but proguard then complains. is there a way to avoid that without disabling proguard?

Comment: @lahsrah Do you have custom Java jar/aar(s) that you are also packaging with your CIL assemblies? / What is your Proguard issue?

Comment: No, It complains about packagge / class naming errors. for the Broadcast receiver i am giving a custom name to.

Comment: @lahsrah Proguard does not touch CIL assemblies and I use it all time to strip down Google Play, etc... when publishing release mode apks. The only thing that the `Name` is going to do is update your manifest so I would look at your Proguard errors as this is not the cause... Post another question with your Proguard build output/warning/errors in another question.