# Xamarin.Android NetworkStatusChangedReceiver gives unhandled exception whenever i add its receiver in manifest file

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.android

Without the broadcast receiver, the code works fine but as soon as I convert it to BR and add the code in receiver tag in the manifest, it gives me a unhandled exception in visual studio 2017.
Nothing is displayed or no line is highlighted in the error.

AndroidManifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.android.tourist" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application android:label="Tourist">
    <receiver android:name=".NetworkStateChangeReceiver" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

NetworkChangeReceiver.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Net;
using Android.Util;
using Java.Lang;

namespace Tourist {
    class NetworkChangeReceiver : BroadcastReceiver {

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (context != null) {
                ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);
                NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.ActiveNetworkInfo;
                bool d = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.IsConnected;
                if (d) {
                    Toast.MakeText(context, "Connected", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                } else {
                    Toast.MakeText(context, "Connected", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SushiHangover said, `Xamarin` [auto-generates class ids if you do not specify one via an `Attribute`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37438585/how-to-know-configure-xamarin-android-generated-package-name/37444345#37444345). `Xamarin` uses `Attributes` in code to fill in the `Manifest` when building. [Here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/broadcast-receivers/#Creating_a_Broadcast_Receiver) is the document about how to create a `BraoadcastReceiver` with `Attributes`.

When you use `Attributes` for your `BroadcastReceiver` :

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = false)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Net.ConnectivityManager.ConnectivityAction })]
public class NetworkChangeReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
```

It will auto-generates into the `Manifest`.

Comment: Gotcha..Thanks :)