# Xamarin + Mvvmcross + Multidex crash when change on/offline

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, reachability, android-multidex

Greetings colleagues from the world xamarin. I need help.

I developed an application in Xamarin with Mvvmcross 4.4 and Firebase. In the Android project I had to implement multidex. The issue that occurs is when the application is running and the connection is lost (airplane mode, wifi off, etc) or vice versa.

In the custom list to build the multidex, all the main dependencies to Firebase, the application itself and the framework, are placed in the main file.

The reported crash however expresses this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.developer.appname.Reachability: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.developer.appname.Reachability" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.developer.appname-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.developer.appname-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver()ActivityThread.java:2926
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800()ActivityThread.java:172
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage()ActivityThread.java:1499
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage()Handler.java:102
android.os.Looper.loop()Looper.java:145
android.app.ActivityThread.main()ActivityThread.java:5832
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke()Method.java:372
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()ZygoteInit.java:1399
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main()ZygoteInit.java:1194
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.developer.appname.Reachability" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.developer.appname-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.developer.appname-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass()BaseDexClassLoader.java:56
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass()ClassLoader.java:511
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass()ClassLoader.java:469
android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver()ActivityThread.java:2921
... 9 more
```

Reachability checks the state of the connection and is used from the core:

```
public class Reachability : BroadcastReceiver, IReachability { ... }

<application android:name=".appname" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:allowBackup="true">
    <receiver android:name=".Reachability">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

If the application is launched offline it is detected correctly and proceeds to display the expected data from cache. The same happens when the app is launched and there is connection that the data is displayed in real time from firebase. **Emphasizing, it only fails when the connection change to on or off, according to the previous state.**

Thank you very much, any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unable to instantiate receiver com.developer.appname.Reachability: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.developer.appname.Reachability"

I have reproduced your problem and found a solution. As SushiHangover said, Xamarin [auto-generates class ids if you do not specify one via an Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37438585/how-to-know-configure-xamarin-android-generated-package-name/37444345#37444345). Xamarin uses `Attributes` in code to fill in the `Manifest` when building. [Here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/broadcast-receivers/#Creating_a_Broadcast_Receiver) is the document about how to create a `BraoadcastReceiver` with `Attributes`.

When you use `Attributes` for your `BroadcastReceiver` :

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = false)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Net.ConnectivityManager.ConnectivityAction })]
public class Reachability : BroadcastReceiver { ... }
```

Register your `BroadcastReceiver` :

```
Reachability mReceiver = new Reachability ();
RegisterReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.ConnectivityAction));
```

It works fine.

Comment: Thanks @York Shen, your advice has been very useful. That and during implementation of the application, reachability service is registered as singleton, to be used from the core. 

However, when an OnReceive occurs, I assumed that another copy of the service is used, different from the one registered in the setup. Knowing this, the variable used for the required Action inside Reachability class, I declared it as static and from there, everything has worked well.